# ¿Cómo accedo a la API de Google con diferentes cuentas de usuario?

Tags: google-api, google-drive, google-oauth

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en ASP.NET MVC (C#), la cual trabaja con la API de Google Drive. He conseguido todo el tema de la autenticación mediante OAuth 2.0 y trabajo perfectamente con la API. El problema es que después de iniciar sesión y darle permisos a mi aplicación para trabajar, si accedo a la URL de mi web desde otro equipo no me pide la autorización, sino que trabaja con la cuenta que ya se había autenticado en un principio.

Es decir, necesito poder acceder a mi web y trabajar con Google Drive con diferentes cuentas de usuario. Donde cada uno se autentica y trabaja con su Google Drive.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService GetService_v3()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/client_secret.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            String FolderPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~");
            String FilePath = Path.Combine(FolderPath, "DriveServiceCredentials.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(FilePath, true)).Result;
        }

        //Create Drive API service.
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "GoogleDriveRestAPI-v3",
        });

        return service;
    }
```

Comment: Deberías aportar el código con el que la aplicación hace la autenticación, aunque creo que el problema es más de autorización. Si no vemos como trabaja la aplicación, poco podemos ayudar.

Comment: @RogerTorné ya he incluido el código